# CodeIgniter routes.php using RegExp

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, url

I have url this type:

```
/12,434/
```

routes.php contain:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['([0-9\,]+)']="route/index/$1";
```

Url /12,434/ open 404 page. How fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to include the forward slash within character class,

```
$route['([0-9\,\/]+)']="route/index/$1";
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM8fF9/8)

Answer (score 0):

You should allow `comma` in URL from `application/config/config.php` file:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.,:_\-';
                                            ^ added here
```